# How to fix ' KeyError: 'accuracy' ' when running flowers_tf_lite.ipynb?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keyerror

When I run the `flowers_tf_lite.ipynb` script.

[**Link to flowers_tf_lite.ipynb script**](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/flowers_tf_lite.ipynb)

The getting `KeyError: 'accuracy'` error stopped the program.

How can I solve this type of error?

```
acc = history.history['accuracy']

val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

loss = history.history['loss']

val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)

plt.plot(acc, label='Training Accuracy')

plt.plot(val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')

plt.legend(loc='lower right')

plt.ylabel('Accuracy')

plt.ylim([min(plt.ylim()),1])

plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')


plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)

plt.plot(loss, label='Training Loss')

plt.plot(val_loss, label='Validation Loss')

plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.ylabel('Cross Entropy')

plt.ylim([0,1.0])

plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')

plt.xlabel('epoch')

plt.show()
```

[Img of KeyError: 'accuracy' error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdLVO.png)

Answer (score 12):

The accuracy metric is named as 'acc' and 'val_acc' after model compile, you can check that using

```
model.metrics_names
```

which will give you

> ['loss', 'acc', 'val_acc']

So you just need to change first 2 lines is above code

```
acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
```